# Java - check if ObjectInputStream.readUTF() is null, or run in separate threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make a chat server (as a smaller part of a game I'm coding) that accepts two clients. The way I have done this so far is by creating two completely different sets of a Socket, ObjectInputStream, and ObjectOutput stream.

```
    private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output2;
private ObjectInputStream input2;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;
private Socket connection2;
static final int PORT = 6789;
```

The outputting is working just fine, but the input method is not working as planned. This is the input method:

```
    //runs while conversation is active
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    waitForConnection();
    setupStreams();
    String message = " You are now connected! ";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);
    do{
            message = input.readUTF();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
            message = input2.readUTF();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
    }while(!message.contains("END"));
}
```

The line `message = input.readUTF();` is waiting for there to be something to read. Is there a way to check if there is something to read and only set message equal to it if not null? No, `if(input.readUTF() != null)` does not work. Alternatively, I think there would be a way to do this with multiple threads, but I do not have a good grasp on how threads work, so if someone could give me an example, that would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

readUTF() is considered a blocking call, which means when it is called, it will hold up the thread until it returns a value. Even if you were to nullcheck, it will still block your thread from continuing until something came through the stream (whether it be a string or a null).

To handle something like a multithreaded connection:

1. Create a class that implements Runnable

   ```
   class User implements Runnable {

   }
   ```
2. In that class, add you in\out stream. Make sure they're aren't static so they're instance variables. You are gonna want a new in/out stream for each connection

   class User implements Runnable {
         DataOutputStream out;
         DataInputStream in;
         Socket socket;

   ```
    public User(Socket s) {
          socket = s;
    }

    public void run() {
         try {
              out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
              //same with inputstream

              String input;
              while(!(input = in.readUTF()).equals("END")) {
                   //do something with input
               }
         }
    }
   ```

   }
3. When your server accepts a connection...

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executors = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); //contains your threads
        ServerSocket ss;

        while(true)
             executor.execute(new User(ss.accept()));
   }
   ```

ServerSocket.accept() is also a blocking call, which means the loop it's being called in will block (wait) until a user is accepted. This is called Blocking-IO.

All read calls from java.io are blocking.

DataInputStream.readUTF
DataInputStream.readInt
ObjectInputStream.readObject

If you want a system where methods such as these don't block, I suggest looking into the java.nio package (new IO). It far more advanced in my opinion, especially for someone who doesn't have a grasp on basic networking yet, but non-blocking IO's allow for your underlying OS to inform your application when to read/write (through a selector), thus removing the need for blocking calls.

Other than that, there is no way you can prevent readUTF to stop blocking, or somehow skip it without data coming through it.

Comment: Sorry for the horrible appeal of my answer. I answered from a phone. I'll hop on a computer to clean it up